# Send std::vector<float> over TCP, from boost::asio to QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, networking, boost-asio

The server needs to send a `std::vector<float>` to a `Qt` application over a TCP socket. I am using Qt 5.7.

On the server side, using `boost::asio`:

```
std::vector<float> message_ = {1.2, 8.5};
asio::async_write(socket_, asio::buffer<float>(message_),
    [this, self](std::error_code ec, std::size_t)
```

This works and I manage to get it back on my client using `boost::asio`'s `read_some()`. As both `Qt` and `asio` have their own event manager, I want to avoid using `asio` in my `Qt` app.

So on the client side I have (which does not work):

client.h:

```
#define FLOATSIZE 4
QTcpSocket *m_socket;
QDataStream m_in;
QString *m_string;
QByteArray m_buff;
```

client.cpp (constructor):

```
m_in.setDevice(m_socket);
m_in.setFloatingPointPrecision(QDataStream::SinglePrecision);
// m_in.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
```

client.cpp (read function, which is connected via `QObject::connect(m_socket, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, &mywidget::ask2read);` ):

```
uint availbytes = m_socket->bytesAvailable(); // which is 8, so that seems good
while (availbytes >= FLOATSIZE)
{
    nbytes = m_in.readRawData(m_buff.data(), FLOATSIZE);

    bool conv_ok = false;
    const float f = m_buff.toFloat(&conv_ok);

    availbytes = m_socket->bytesAvailable();

    m_buff.clear();
}
```

The `m_buff.toFloat()` call returns `0.0` which is a fail according to the Qt doc. I have tried to change the float precision, little or big endian, but I can not manage to get my `std::vector<float>` back. Any hints?

Edit: everything runs on the same PC/compiler.

Edit: see my answer for a solution and sehe's for more detail on what is going on

Comment: @molbdnilo well a float is 4 bytes and a vector of two floats is 8 bytes, and see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22869206/7272199 . My understanding is that there is no serialization going on here, am I right ?

Comment: @molbdnilo yes it is (IOW asio does not _have_ a serialization format, that's your job)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue, by editing the `Qt` side (client), to read the socket:

```
uint availbytes = m_socket->bytesAvailable();
while (availbytes >= 4)
{
    char buffer[FLOATSIZE];
    nbytes = m_in.readRawData(buffer, FLOATSIZE);    
    float f = bytes2float(buffer);
    availbytes = m_socket->bytesAvailable();
}
```

I use those two conversion functions, `bytes2float` and `bytes2int`:

```
float bytes2float(char* buffer)
{
    union {
        float f;
        uchar b[4];
    } u;

    u.b[3] = buffer[3];
    u.b[2] = buffer[2];
    u.b[1] = buffer[1];
    u.b[0] = buffer[0];

    return u.f;
}
```

and:

```
int bytes2int(char* buffer)
{
    int a = int((unsigned char)(buffer[3]) << 24 |
        (unsigned char)(buffer[2]) << 16 |
        (unsigned char)(buffer[1]) << 8 |
        (unsigned char)(buffer[0]));
    return a;
}
```

I also found that function to display bytes, which is useful to see what is going on behind the scene (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063757/7272199):

```
template <typename T>
void print_bytes(const T& input, std::ostream& os = std::cout)
{
  const unsigned char* p = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&input);
  os << std::hex << std::showbase;
  os << "[";
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<sizeof(T); ++i)
    os << static_cast<int>(*(p++)) << " ";
  os << "]" << std::endl;;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Re. [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41726262/85371): Which side is this on? Also, are your platforms not the same (OS/architecture?). I had assumed from the question that both processes run on the same PC and compiler etc.

For one thing, you can see that [ASIO does **not** do anything related to endianness](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05f8f1cb2de51536).

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

#include <iostream>

void print_bytes(unsigned char const* b, unsigned char const* e)
{
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << "[ ";
    while (b!=e)
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(*b++) << " ";
    std::cout << "]\n";
}

template <typename T> void print_bytes(const T& input) {
    using namespace std;
    print_bytes(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>(std::addressof(*begin(input))), 
                reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const*>(std::addressof(*end(input))));
}

int main() {
    float const fs[] { 1.2, 8.5 };
    std::cout << "fs:     "; print_bytes(fs);

    {
        std::vector<float> gs(2);
        asio::buffer_copy(asio::buffer(gs), asio::buffer(fs));

        for (auto g : gs) std::cout << g << " "; std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "gs:     "; print_bytes(gs);
    }
    {
        std::vector<char> binary(2*sizeof(float));
        asio::buffer_copy(asio::buffer(binary), asio::buffer(fs));
        std::cout << "binary: "; print_bytes(binary);

        std::vector<float> gs(2);
        asio::buffer_copy(asio::buffer(gs), asio::buffer(binary));

        for (auto g : gs) std::cout << g << " "; std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << "gs:     "; print_bytes(gs);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
fs:     [ 9a 99 99 3f 00 00 08 41 ]
1.2 8.5 
gs:     [ 9a 99 99 3f 00 00 08 41 ]
binary: [ 9a 99 99 3f 00 00 08 41 ]
1.2 8.5 
gs:     [ 9a 99 99 3f 00 00 08 41 ]
```

### Theory

I suspect the Qt side ruins things. Since the naming of the function `readRawData` certainly implies a lack of endianness awareness, I'd guess your system's endianness wreaks havoc (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2945192/85371, also the comment).

### Suggestion

In that case, consider using Boost Endian.

Comment: I edited my answer so it is clearer. Yes everything runs on the same PC/compiler. Thank you for your input it helps me understand better what is going on, I will have a look at boost endian to improve my code

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bad idea to use high level send method server side (you try to send a c++ vector) and low level client side.

I'm quite sure there is an endianness problem somewhere.

Anyway try to do this client side:

```
char buffer[FLOATSIZE];
bytes = m_in.readRawData(buffer, FLOATSIZE);    

if (bytes != FLOATSIZE) 
     return ERROR;

const float f = (float)(ntohl(*((int32_t *)buffer)));
```

If boost::asio uses the network byte order for the floats (as it should), this will work.

Comment: I get huge non-sense values for my floats using this, so asio might mess with the endianness

Comment: The send method on the asio side is as lowlevel as it gets! It's bitwise serialization. It does *not* meddle with endianness.

Comment: @sehe would you have any clue of what is going on there ?

Comment: I'd surely be writing answers then. Maybe if you can present a SSCCE client/server (I'll even install Qt for you)

Comment: @sehe I managed to work it out, writing my own conversion functions. thanks to both of you